# ResolutionContext.Items throwing exception from Automapper 9.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I tried to upgrade my solution from `Automapper` **V8.1.1** to `Automapper` **V9.0.0**
but I faced one issue.

I have two scenarios with one map. In the first scenario I pass data to the resolution context:

```
attachments = _mapper.Map<Attachment[]>(objects.Items, opt => {
            opt.Items[Constants.IncludeDescription] = true;
        });
```

and another where I do not:

```
attachments = _mapper.Map<Attachment[]>(objects.Items);`
```

**Automapper V9.0.0**:

[image]

**Automapper V8.1.1**:
[image: 2]

Everything working fine for `Automapper` **8.1.1** but with version **9.0.0** `context.Items` throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` (see images above) so I am not sure if this is a bug or not.

Comment: You'll have to do what the message says.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3206

Answer (score 2):

as @LucianBargaoanu noticed from 9.0.0 we need to provide _=>{} so resolutionContext.Items won't throw exception.